# in razor how to have a link to an external url from the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

in my razor page I have.

```
<p>
    <span>Website: </span>
    <span>
        <a href="@(Url.Encode(Model.PrimaryInfo.WebsiteUrl))" target="_blank">@Model.PrimaryInfo.WebsiteUrl</a>
    </span>
</p>
```

when I inspect the element I see.
the page displays as

> Website: https://www.mywebsite.org/

when I inspect element I get

```
<a href="https%3a%2f%2fwww.mywebsite.org%2f" target="_blank">https://www.mywebsite.org/</a>
```

and when I click the link I get

> [HttpException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.Path
>   value was detected from the client (:).]
>   System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig() +9939972
>   System.Web.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context) +53

Comment: Remove Url.Encode.

Comment: still get potentially dangerous request without the url.encode

Comment: This is extraordinarily dangerous but you should be able to just [Html.Raw()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.118).aspx) the value out.  [Be really careful here, Raw() is extraordinarily dangerous](https://kevinchalet.com/2018/01/09/why-you-should-never-use-html-raw-in-your-razor-views/).  [Dangers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31463823/prevent-xss-attacks-and-still-use-html-raw) and google more, please understand what it does.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this

```
public static class LinkHelper{
public static string ExternalLink(this HtmlHelper helper, string url, string text)
    {
        return String.Format("<a href='http://{0}' target="_blank">{1}</a>", url,text);
}}
```

and in view

```
@Html.ExternalLink("www.google.com", "Google")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your checklist:

1. Non-unicode datatype not used: validate that you are storing URLs in the database as an NVarChar type and don't use VarChar
2. No need to encode: remove the encoding.
3. Validate that you are not violating request validation scheme as per .Net.
   Please refer to hanslman article: 
   https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx